# I want to change background color after clicking using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Following is my code:

```
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="grid_table">
    <tr class="grid_caption"><td class="grid_caption">Customer Name</td></tr>
    <? if(count($arrResult) > 0) { ?>
        <? foreach($arrResult as $row) { ?>
        <tr class="grid_row"  ><td class="grid_row" onClick="javascript:return selectCustomer(this,<?=$row['customer_id']?>);"><?=HTMLVarConv($row['Name'])?></td></tr>
        <? } ?>
    <? } ?>
</table>
```

here i got the list of customer
but when i click on this customer name then its background color should be change..
here is my javascript function

```
function selectCustomer(row, id) {
    alert(row);
    var mark_color = '#fdf5d2' //'#c1c1ff'
    var current_row = '#aad4f0' //'#e8e8e8'
    if (row.style.backgroundColor == current_row) {
        row.style.backgroundColor = mark_color;
    }
    else if (row.style.backgroundColor == mark_color) {
        row.style.backgroundColor = current_row;
    }
    $("#editCustomer").attr("src","editcustomer.php?customer_id="+id+"&showmenu=0");
    $("#ajaxList").show();
    return;
}
```

but not changing what the problem ????
please help me

Comment: I'm no PHP expert, but I do see that you are using an `if-else-if` statement. This means that something will happen only if one of those two things are true. Are you sure that `row.style.backgroundColor` definitely is one of those two values -- `mark_color` and `current_row`? You might want to run `console.log(row.style.backgroundColor);` to make sure you have the correct value for that style attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is perfect well:
Css::

```
.grid_row
{
    padding: 3px;
    border-right: 1px solid #849AAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #849AAA;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.evn
{
    padding: 3px;
    border-right: 1px solid #849AAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #849AAA;
    vertical-align:top;
    background-color: white;
    /*document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';*/
    cursor: pointer;
    }
.selevn
{
    padding: 3px;
    border-right: 1px solid #849AAA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #849AAA;
    vertical-align:top;
    background-color: silver;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Following is my Javascript code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var prevRow = null;
function selectCustomer(it,id) {
    if (it.className.substring(0, 3) == "sel")
    {
        it.className = it.className.substring(3, 6);
        prevRow = null;
    }
  else
    {
        it.className = "sel" + it.className;
        if (prevRow != null)
        {
           prevRow.className = prevRow.className.substring(3, 6);
        }
        prevRow = it;
    }
    $("#editCustomer").attr("src","editcustomer.php?customer_id="+id+"&showmenu=0");
    $("#ajaxList").show();
    return ;
}
```

THis is my code:

```
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="grid_table">
        <tr class="grid_caption"><td class="grid_caption">Customer Name</td></tr>
        <? if(count($arrResult) > 0) { ?>
        <? foreach($arrResult as $row) { ?>
        <tr class="evn"  onClick="javascript:return selectCustomer(this,<?=$row['customer_id']?>);" ><td class="grid_row" id="<?= $row['customer_id']?>"  ><?=HTMLVarConv($row['Name'])?></td></tr>
        <? } ?>
        <? } ?>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged "jquery", why not make use of it instead of inline `onclick` handlers? It can be as simple as: http://jsfiddle.net/t7vj5/.

```
$("td.grid_row").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");

    $("#editCustomer").attr("src", "editcustomer.php");
    $("#ajaxList").show();

    return false;
});
```

And the CSS:

```
td.grid_row {
    background-color: #fdf5d2;
}

td.grid_row.selected {
    background-color: #aad4f0;
}
```

Just make sure to execute the JavaScript after the rows have been created, or wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.grid_row').click(function(){
$('.grid_row').css("background-color","#aad4f0");
$(this).css("background-color","#fdf5d2");
});
```

edit: Oh and you can remove the onclick= function
The above lines are sufficient for what you want to do as long as the class gridrow is there.

This will change the color to #fdf5d2 on clicking and change the color back to #aad4f0 for all other cells on clicking on another row.
If you don't want the color to change back, remove the first line